# How can I model a database structure to retain student information?

Tags: mysql, database-design, php, phpmyadmin

I am completely new to databases and SQL.

I have generated a database in myphpAdmin consisting of a table with the columns `(name, student number, grade)`. Basically this database will hold the *grades* for all the *students* in a *school*. In my web application program, the index.php displays all information in the database on the browser.

So basically each *student* will have a row in the database. Over time, the *grades* for each *student* will be added to the database once they sit an *exam*. How can I just add more information to the *grade* column of each *student* row without losing the *grades* that are already there? (As the UPDATE operation in SQL seems to override the old data).

Or am I going about this the wrong way and need to structure each *student* as a database in themselves and then add their *grades* into those individual databases, with *grade1*, *grade2*, *grade3*, etc.?

Comment: Well... tables are not the same thing as databases so you need to start with learning that critical piece. As for your schema, you probably want another table "grades" (student number, grade) separate from your "students" table (student number, name). You insert 1 record into students for each student, and insert 1 record into grades for each test result. Student number is the key relation between the tables.

Comment: Thanks for the help, its a steep learning curve only starting off.

Answer (score 1):

You need to normalize the design. A column can, under sane circumstances, only hold a datum (singular).

So something like this

```
CREATE TABLE student (
  studentid int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE class (
  classid   int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  classname text
);
CREATE TABLE student_class_grade (
  classid   int REFERENCES class,
  studentid int REFERENCES student,
  grade     float
);
```

This is super simple, so each student has a `studentid`, each class has a `classid`, and you can put as many entries as needed for `stupid_class_grade`. This doesn't account for the extra complexity needed for weighing tests and homework differently in the same class.

Answer (score 1):

At a minimum, you would probably want to have at least two tables in your database, `student` and `graded_assignment` (or `graded_test`, if all grades are based on tests only).

`student` would have the student's name and id.

`graded_assignment` would have the student's ID (to tie the grade to a specific student), the total possible point value of the assignment, and the actual number of points earned by the student.

The total grade would be calculated through a query, something like:

```
SELECT s.name, s.id, SUM(g.points_earned) * 100 / SUM(g.points_possible) as percent_grade
  FROM student s
         INNER JOIN graded_assignment g ON (s.id = g.student_id)
 GROUP BY s.name, s.id
;
```

In reality, you would probably have a separate `assignment` table that would list information about each assignment/test/whatever, including the total points available, and the `graded_assignment` table would link back to that.

In all likelihood, you'd have a number of other tables. Students would be in one or more `class`; each `class` would have an `instructor`, who might teach multiple `class`es; assignments would be tied to a `class`. You might even have a scenario where an `instructor` teaches the same `course` to multiple `class`es, which might change what an `assignment` got tied to.